# How can I unset the following eventhandler?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I've set an eventhandler to an event like this:

```
 frm.FormClosed += (sender,  args) =>
                    {
                        if (this.myGrid.Enabled)
                        {
                            this.myGrid.Select();
                        }
                    };
 frm.Show();
```

I want to hang out the eventhandler after the form was closed.

Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but what do you mean by 'hang out the event handler'?

Comment: @kenny I think he meant to unset / remove the event.

Comment: @pro Why exactly you want to do this?

Comment: @Meryovi like frm.FormClose -= (lamdba??)   Not sure, it's probably easier to change the lambda to a method and the remove that.

Comment: Hi, yes I want to unset / remove the eventhandler from the event.

Comment: @kenny It's easier and more maintainable, but maybe he doesn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to hang out the eventhandler after the form was closed.

I assume you want to remove it.

1. Not necessary, don't waste time on it. When the Form is closed (and Disposed), the eventhandler will be collected too. It is a member of the same Form, that follows from the word `this` in the code.
2. If you still want to remove it, you will need a copy:

   ```
    FormClosedEventhandler closeHandler;  // class member



    closeHandler = (sender,  args) =>  
         {
            if (this.myGrid.Enabled)
            {
               this.myGrid.Select();
            }
         };

    frm.FormClosed += closeHandler ; // OnLoad
    ...

    frm.FormClosed -= closeHandler ; // OnClose
   ```

Comment: If you create two identical lambdas, they'll not necessarily be the same reference ([this topic was discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4807808/880802)), so you shouldn't rely on that but rather store the reference in a variable.

Comment: @Tobias: OK, thanks. I've seen it being used but it looks awful anyway. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean how to remove you event handler from the event, then you won't be able to use an anonymous delegate but you can create a method with the same parameters and same code and then:

```
private void EventHandler(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.myGrid.Enabled)
     {
        this.myGrid.Select();
     }
}

frm.FormClosed += EventHandler; // Attach the event handler
frm.FormClosed -= EventHandler; // Remove the event handler
```

Comment: 'EventHandler' already is the name of a delegate in the library.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's not an issue but the OP can probably choose a meaningful name